# Tensorflow warning message

Tags: tensorflow

I am receiving the following warning when I am using tensorflow. How can I fix this warning?

2020-08-10 15:51:38.845771: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

2020-08-10 15:51:38.856311: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fb9ed515de0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:

2020-08-10 15:51:38.856329: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Did you check at these threads yet?   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44683#issuecomment-790589399       https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44683#issuecomment-808859600